# Can git log ignore pieces of text matching a given regex when doing rename detection?

Tags: git, git-log

I have a large commit in a git repository which renames a lot of files and restructures the directory layout. At the same time, there are extensive changes to the comments in the source files. Now I would like to find out which file ended up where.

I have tried to use git log for this like so:

```
git log -B -M50% -C50% -w --summary -1 -l 10000 .
```

This helps a bit but for files containing many comments it doesn't detect the rename. For this I would have to lower the similarity to 20% or less, which gives a lot of false positives.

Now, is there a way to tell git to ignore the comments before calculating the similarity index?